# Is there a Reactive Framework Subject that buffers until it doesn't need to?

Tags: .net, system.reactive

When adapting 3rd party libraries to expose `IObservable`, it is sometimes unavoidable that you have to use something like a `ReplaySubject` to buffer results for the short period after you become aware that a stream is available and before you can get someone to subscribe to it.

A `ReplaySubject` with a short time period will 'usually' work, but not always, and then is wasteful, maintaining a rolling queue that may not be necessary once a subscriber is listening.

Is there a suggested pattern for a 'subject which buffers until someone is listening?'

Comment: Can you let us know why you think a `ReplaySubject` is wasteful? Can you also give us an example bit of code to demonstrate what you're trying to do?

Comment: @SebastianGood If you can subscribe a `ReplaySubject` to it, why can't you subscribe the actual listener at that point as well?

Comment: @IlianPinzon: our example is a socket interface. When a connection is accepted, it is itself an observable. We emit the connection to a listener (e.g. WhenConection), who then subscribes to the messages (e.g. cxn.WhenMessage). Ideally, we'd only accept the client connection on subscribe to cxn.WhenMessage, but with our 3rd party library, we start receiving messages immediately and can't lose them while the listener is waiting to subscribe.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I simply assume the the memory overhead of the rolling buffer is something I can avoid, because once the listener is subscribed, I'm happy to let him deal with buffering as he likes.

Comment: @SebastianGood - Memory overhead? Unless you're programming the Micro.NET framework that shouldn't be an issue these days. Is this just a case of premature optimisation?

Comment: @Enigmativity: no, we are sometimes dealing with large messages. If a replay subject permanently holds on to this data, perhaps once for each connection, it represents an unnecessary memory leak.

Comment: @SebastianGood - This then is a matter of objects going out of scope, not about `ReplaySubject`.

Comment: @Enigmativity, so long as I am pushing events through the `ReplaySubject`, I pay the price for its buffering (timestamping, walking queue of messages, etc.). I think I've realized what I really want is a `ReplayOnceSubject`. But I've instead changed the API I'm writing so this isn't required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer appears to be "No". You could write one on your own with relatively little trouble, though it would look a lot like a `ReplaySubject`, just one which drops its queue entirely upon subscription. Constructing one from pieces is fraught with race conditions.

The problem arose for me when I wrote an API that exposed `IObservable<TConnection>` where `TConnection` had a member `IObservable<TMessage>`. People who observed the new `TConnection` needed to be sure that they didn't miss any `TMessage`s on that connection. The underlying event source made that slightly awkward. I require that, if an observer does not want to miss any messages, that he subscribe to the `IObservable<TMessage>` *before* the call to `OnNext(TConnection)` completes. This is almost always what someone will want to do, they just need to be sure they don't do something silly like `.ObserveOn(Scheduler.TaskPool)` for their `IObservable<TConnection>`. If programmers agree to do this, then indeed no buffering is required at all (in this particular implementation) and a regular `Subject` will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I have understood the problem correctly. But based on your last sentence `subject which buffers until someone is listening`, you can do something like below extension method

```
static IObservable<T> BufferUntillSubscribe<T>(this IObservable<T> obs)
{
    var replay = new ReplaySubject<T>();
    var disposable = obs.Subscribe(replay);
    return Observable.CreateWithDisposable<T>((subscriber) =>
    {
        disposable.Dispose();
        return replay.Merge(obs).Subscribe(subscriber);
    });
}
```

Comment: Neat idea.  To avoid some race conditions, perhaps inside the `Observable.Create` delegate call do: `var d = replay.Concat(obs).Subscribe(subscriber); replay.OnComplete(); disposable.Dispose(); return d;`

Comment: Though you could still lose messages after you complete the replay subject and before Concat subscribes to the hot observable.